# Проблема доработки скомпилированного js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

У меня есть скомпилированный js файл, где вместе пару библиотек, а так же некоторый пользовательский скрипт. Изначально сайт был одностраничный, а теперь я дорабатываю ещё несколько страниц.

В консоли возникает ошибка о том, что некоторые элементы на моих страницах не найдены и код перестаёт работать.

Можно было бы к моим страницам не подключать этот файл, а делать всё в другом, но я собираюсь вёрстку в дальнейшем натягивать на WP.

Подскажите, какие могут быть решения?

Comment: Ваш вопрос ни о чём... Какие элементы не найдены? Что перестаёт работать? Что и куда Вы собираетесь натягивать?

Comment: XelaNimed вы не поняли суть вопроса, не важно какие элементы не найдены, перестаёт работать весь функционал, натягивать на WordPress

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде есть строки, которые ищут элемент на странице, ошибка возникает в том, что элемент не удалось найти и в таком случае скрипт перестает работать. Добавьте дополнительные проверки на undefined и всё будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо хоть какое то решение, но уж очень много проверок нужно создавать, но на крайний случай сделаю так)